Vue 3: Passing Data via Props and Vue Router Results in Invalid Params Warning
I'm working with Vue 3 and trying to pass data between views using Vue Router. My goal is to pass data from JobSelection.vue to Invoice.vue through router parameters
In index.js I defined the props as follows:
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/joblist',
    name: 'Joblist',
    component: () => import('../views/JobSelection.vue'),
  },
  {
    path: '/invoice',
    name: 'Invoice',
    component: () => import('../views/Invoice.vue'),
    props: (route) => ({ selectedEntries: route.params.selectedEntries }),
  },
]

Inside my JobSelection.vue , I use this method to navigate and pass data:
const navigateInvoice = () => {
    router.push({
      name: 'Invoice',
      params: { selectedEntries: 'Test' }
    });
  };

But I get the warning: [Vue Router warn]: Discarded invalid param(s)
I am just passing a test string. Why is it discarded?
My Invoice.vue looks like:
<script setup>
  // Declare the props expected from the router
  const props = defineProps({
    selectedEntries: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    }
  });

  // Log selectedEntries to the console
  console.log(props.selectedEntries);
</script>

What am I doing wrong?

path: '/invoice' contains no params

vue-router can set component props using route params or queries.  if "selectedEntries" is the name of the prop, you need a param with the same name.  try path: '/invoice/:selectedEntries'

The  selectedEntries prop needs type of  Array but got a string Test

route.params.SomeParameterName is used to extract a URL parameter from the current URL. So, when you type route.params.selectedEntries, Vue looks in the current URL for a URL parameter called selectedEntries (for example, https://example.com/invoice?selectedEntries=waffles).
Therefore, when defining your route, in addition to defining the URL path, you also need to define any URL parameters you would like to use. This can be done by simply placing a color (:) before the parameter name. In your case, this would be as follows:
{
  path: '/invoice/:selectedEntries',
  name: 'Invoice',
  component: () => import('../views/Invoice.vue'),
  props: (route) => ({ selectedEntries: route.params.selectedEntries }),
}

Now, whenever you navigate to https://yourWebsite.com/invoice, Vue will be expecting the selectedEntries URL parameter, and will pass it as a prop to your destination component.
